# PSR-4 autoloading not working for class declared from parent directory

Tags: composer-php

I have the following declaration for PSR-4 autoloading in my composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "../source/",
        "ACME\\": "source/"
    }
}
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
acme-testbed/
    framework/
        source/
            Interfaces/
                Helpers/
                    I18N.php
            Helpers/
                I18N.php
        composer.json
    source/
        Interfaces/
            Modules/
                Frontend.php
        Modules/
            Frontend.php
```

This way, I can do things like `\ACME\Helpers\I18N::getLanguages()` or `\Application\Modules\Frontend::setLanguage("es")` (I would really use aliases to do just `I18N::getLanguages()` or `Frontend::setLanguage("es")` but it's just for illustrative purposes).

The problem I have is my application finds every single class under the ACME namespace but not the Application one. As you can see, every declaration for the ACME namespace is inside the `framework` folder (same as the composer.json file) but every declaration of the Application namespace lies within the application root, which is its parent directory.

How can I adjust the composer.json file so I can use both namespaced declarations?

**EDIT #1:** just realized I shown the wrong folder structure (there's no `Application` folder for the Application namespace declarations). My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

If your namespaces match directories names, you should define autoload rules like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "../source/Application/",
        "ACME\\": "source/"
    }
}
```

In your case `Application` namespace is in `acme-testbed/source/Application`, so you need to point it directly.

Comment: Bleh... I made the wrong folder structure when asking my question. Sorry about that. There's no Application folder.